# Sql Server IN Clause

Tags: sql-server

How to remove single Quote from given select Query. It is give me Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.

```
SELECT * FROM Member
WHERe MemberId IN ('1,2,3')
```

Comment: I have other question like... if i pass value like

Comment: Declare @MId = '1,2,3' then Use in Query like SELECT * FROM Member Where MemberId IN (@MId) then what can i do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use single quotes for integer field:

```
SELECT * FROM Member WHERE MemberId IN (1,2,3)
```

You should use quotes for varchar fields, like:

```
SELECT * FROM Member WHERE Name IN ('John','George','Amanda')
```